# Unit Testing: Agile and knowing what to test? Testing against requirements?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, bdd

Before, I used to implement unit tests just to test whether a method *works.* But after  reading in other places, it appears I should be testing when a method *fails.*

For example, a method should throw a Exception what passed a string.

Where do these requirements come from?

I am working in an agile team, so we get user stories which include basic requirements of what a function of the application will do. These basic requirements include very *simple*  requirements (i.e. password should be at the most 8 characters in length).

I then create tasks from this user story taking into consideration the requirements.

Hence, when testing...  what, exactly, should I test?

I suppose I should test that the method (which is part of a task which is part of a user story) functions the way it should, but I should also test that it fails when it should?

For example, passing 12 characters to a parameter (password) for a method when the requirement is a maximum of 8 characters. Do I have to include a test case for that?

Does anyone know of a good resource or link that explains a little more about this subject?

I presume without requirements I can only test whether the method succeeds and not and whether it fails, as I would not be aware of when it should fail because there are no requirements?

Any help anyone can offer would be really helpful.

Comment: have you thought about [corner or edge cases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_case) for your stories requirements?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're reading too much into test for failure. All it means is write the test before you write the code (apart from a stub that will always return an invalid value like null). That way you know you have that code to write when it fails. Then, you write the code and test again. The test should now pass. Test-driven development should always work like this.

Comment: +1. Even better, your test should fail _with a clear, meaningful error message_ before you write the code to make it pass.

Answer (score 1):

While you certainly can't test *every* possibility, you should at *least* test the possibilities which are considered in the code.

So with your example, where a string passed into a method must be no more than 8 characters (which is a *terrible* requirement for a password, by the way), the method might look something like this:

```
public bool IsPasswordCorrect(string password)
{
    if (password.Length > 8)
        throw new ArgumentException("Password must not be greater than 8 characters.");

    return password == SomeKnownPassword;
}
```

The goal should be 100% code coverage.  This means that each line of code which actually does something should have at least one corresponding test.  So if the only test is for the "happy path" (strings which are no greater than 8 characters) then the `throw` line is never tested.

That line of code is there in response to a requirement, so that requirement should be tested.  In this case you'd have a few tests:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MatchingPasswordsShouldBeAllowed()
{
    // set the known password
    // set the passed password
    // call the method
    // assert that the method returned true
}

[TestMethod]
public void NonMatchingPasswordsShouldNotBeAllowed()
{
    // set the known password
    // set the passed password to something else
    // call the method
    // assert that the method returned false
}

[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
public void PasswordsShouldNotBeGreaterThanEightCharacters()
{
    // set the known password
    // set the passed password to something too long
    // call the method
    // assert that an exception was thrown
}
```

Notice the names of the test methods.  They sound like requirements.  The idea is that stated requirements should be decomposed into actual specifications.  The business requirement was:

> - Passwords should be no longer than 8 characters

But are there implied requirements in there?  Requirements like:

> - A supplied password which matches the known password should result in authentication.
> - A supplied password which does not match the known password should not result in authentication.

After all, the method is doing all of these things.  And if the method is doing something, that something should be tested.  Ultimately, everything that the code does should have at least one corresponding test which maps to a requirement.

In fact, if the tests are written well, they start to *become* the requirements.  Which is good, because it means that the knowledge in question (the requirements) can be kept in one place (the tests) instead of multiple disparate places (tests, code, documents, whiteboard, etc.).

If there's a line of code which isn't executed by a test, then why is that line of code there?  If there's no test for it then there's no requirement for it.  If there's no requirement for it, remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Start with **happy path tests**. Your happy path should be based on use cases from the requirements.

When you cover all the happy paths, continue with **boundary tests**. So when it should be 8 characters passwords , then do tests for 7,8,9 characters and cover the scenarios for that.

After you cover all the happy path and boundary tests, ask yourself **how can I write failing test?** If you can figure it out, then write it. If it's exception that should be raised then cover it. With that in mind you can easily figure it out what should be tested and what is not so much necessary.